# $\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right) = -\frac{1}{u^2}$ for $u \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

My task is the following:

Prove with the product rule:

$\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right) = -\frac{1}{u^2}$ for $u \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

---

Well, I don't know how I could prove the identity with the product rule...
Am I missing something obvious or may the task be wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Take the derivative of $1 = u \cdot \frac{1}{u}$, and deduce the value of $\frac{d}{du}\frac{1}{u}$

Answer (score 0):

Since $1 = u\cdot\frac1u$, differentiating yields
$$0 = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf du}[1] = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf du}\left[u\cdot \frac1u\right]. \tag 1$$
By the product rule, the RHS of (1) is
$$u\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf du}\left[\frac1u\right] + \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf du}[u]\frac1u = u\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf du}\left[\frac1u\right]+\frac1u. \tag 2$$
Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf du}\left[\frac1u\right]=-\frac1{u^2}. $$

Answer (score 0):

The method doesn't really prove that $u\mapsto 1/u$ is differentiable, but that *if* it is, then the derivative must be $u\mapsto -1/u^2$.

Consider $f(u)=1/u$ and $g(u)=u$. Then $f(u)g(u)=1$, for all $u\ne0$. Therefore, *assuming* $f$ is differentiable and differentiating both sides,
$$
f'(u)g(u)+f(u)g'(u)=0
$$
so
$$
uf'(u)=-\frac{1}{u}
$$
and the thesis follows.

---

However this method does not prove $f$ is differentiable. For a counterexample, consider the function
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
-x & \text{if $x$ is rational},\\[6px]
x & \text{if $x$ is irrational}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $F(x)\cdot F(x)=x^2$, so differentiating both sides with the product rule gives
$$
2F'(x)F(x)=2x
$$
and therefore
$$
F'(x)=\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if $x$ is rational and $x\ne0$},\\[6px]
1 & \text{if $x$ is irrational},
\end{cases}
$$
which is an absurd assertion, because $F$ is only continuous at $0$ so it's not differentiable at any $x\ne0$. It's not differentiable at $0$ either.

Of course our $f$ above is not the same as $F$ and it *is* differentiable: one just has to be careful when applying formulas blindly.